# Set absolute position of a view without altering position of other elements ? Should work irrespective of the layout it is contained in

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

So my problem statement goes something like this. I am building a SDK part of which involve changing absolute position of an element on the screen. Now, the element could be contained in any layout Linear, Relative, Table, Grid, Tab or List Layout.

However, I would like to set absolute position of the element on the screen without disturbing position of other elements ?

There are few functions like setTranslationX, but that sets position relative to it's previous sibling. setLeft also doesn't work very well. In Linear Layout, it would readjust width/height and position of other elements in the same layout.

Any ideas ?